# Android Main thread cant handle output and working to hard

Tags: android

I'm trying to draw some shapes but when i load the app there is just a black screen. I've checked the logcat and it says that the output is to much and that the main thread may be working to hard. how do i deal with this.  whenn my app first runs the logcat prints what i want but after a while it just prints `called unimplemented OpenGL ES API` over and over again. How to stop main thread from working so hard.

```
@Override
            public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {

        // Clears the screen and depth buffer.
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();//replace the current matrix with the identity matrix
                main.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= (now+delay)){
            if(starAdded < starTotal) {
                if ((r.nextInt() % 2) == 0) {
                            star[starAdded] = new Star();

                    starAdded++;
                    Log.i("MyGLRenderer", "3 star added");
                }
                else {
                    star[starAdded] = new fourStar();
                    starAdded++;
                    Log.i("MyGLRenderer", "4 star added");
                }
                now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
        for(int a = 0; a < starAdded; a++) {
        star[a].draw(gl);

        }}});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a game thread.. e.g

```
public class GameThread extends Thread{

private static int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS;
private static int FRAME_PERIOD;
private final Game game;
private final GameViewRenderer gameView;
private boolean gameRunning = true;
private boolean running = false;
Handler handler = new Handler();

public GameThread(Game game, GameViewRenderer gameView, int maxFPS, int maxFrameSkips) {
    this.game = game;
    this.gameView = gameView;
    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = maxFrameSkips;
    FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / maxFPS;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long beginTime;
    long timeDiff;
    int sleepTime;
    int framesSkipped;
    beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    framesSkipped = 0;
    gameRunning = game.isRunning();
    game.updateState();                                 // Update game
    gameView.postInvalidate();                          // Render the game
    timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;  // Calculate cycle length
    sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);         // Calculate time available to sleep

    // Checks if got time to sleep, either sleeps thread or catches up
    if (sleepTime > 0) {
        if(gameRunning && running){
            handler.postDelayed(this, sleepTime);
        }
        while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
            game.updateState();                         // Update without rendering
            sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;                  // Add frame period to check if in next frame
            framesSkipped++;
            if(gameRunning && running) {
                this.run();                             // No time to wait! RUN! CATCH UP!
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}
```

}

Or decrease the fps

Comment: thanks a lot. im not totally sure ho to apply this to my code since its in my renderer class. but ill start working on it with your example.

Comment: Well your activity should create a Game (model) and then a View (your renderer)

Simply just create a thread like this, instantiate it with the activity passing it your game and view and then run it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Ive got a problem, ive change the game.upDateState to game.onResume, which seems fine. i also changed the gameView.postInvalidate to gameView.onDrawFrame() but I cant do this because the parameter GL10 is abstract. Do you know of a work around?

Comment: Seems like you're not implementing it in a mvc mannor, without a look at your code I can't really help you I'm afraid